# how to see dc operating region names in cadence DC annotation for MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, cadence

How do I see the operating region names like "active, saturation" in cadence for MOSFET.

I remember getting it by setting up View> DC annotation> Setup > selecting DC operating region > Display > region.

But Now I am getting the region displayed as numbers "0,1,2"

Can someone please tell how to get the operating region names?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In view > DC annotation setup >

select pmos4/nmos4 (corresponding transistor) 
under Display mode choose "component parameter"
under "Expression" select " region"

This will show the short name of region as shown in screenshot , instead of region numbers.

[image: Screenshot for answer]

Answer (score 6):

You can map the 5 regions as follow:

0 cut-off

1 triode

2 sat

3 subth and 4 breakdown

Source for this information, "http://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f/38/t/14626"

Its just encoded that way and you can just know which region it is from the above information, which solves its purpose.